# Can I View Disk Usage in WHM?

Tags: root, disk-usage, webserver

Do you know how I can access [disk usage][1] and analyze all the disk information from disk information from Web Host Manager (WHM)?

WHM is a web application that provides administrative control of your Virtual Private Server (VPS) or dedicated server. You use WHM with cPanel to create individual accounts, add domains, manage hosting features, and perform basic maintenance.

Comment: Can you explain, what is WHM?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just found that I can effortlessly [view disk usage](https://blog.redserverhost.com/use-of-show-current-disk-usage-feature-in-whm/) from whm. It's pretty simple. You can also do this by following the below steps:

1. Log into WHM
2. From the WHM homepage, navigate to *System Health >> Show Current Disk*, and you're done.
3. You can view all the disk partitions, disk usages, and analyze it with different ways.